# Как отсортировать текстовый файл с четверостишьем на список с отдельными словами?

Tags: python

Есть файл с отрывком из Ромео и Джульеты:

> But soft what light through yonder window breaks
>
> It is the east and Juliet is the sun
>
> Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
>
> Who is already sick and pale with grief

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему код ниже бьет каждую строчку на отдельный список и создает двумерный массив, а не перебирает слова в один.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = []
for line in fh:
    thing = line.split()
    lst.append(thing)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

`append` добавляет элемент  в конец списка. Но этот объект - уже список, так что получится вложенный список в список

А вот операция `extend` расширяет первый список, добавив в конец все элементы второго, как и требуется

```
lst.extend(thing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вас интересует практическая, а не академическая сторона вопроса, то модуль [NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit)](https://www.nltk.org/) - как раз предназначен для работы с естественными текстами:

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
try:
    from pathlib import Path       # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path      # Python 2.x  (pip install pathlib2)

words = word_tokenize(Path(r'D:\temp\text.txt').read_text())
```

результат:

```
In [59]: words
Out[59]:
['But',
 'soft',
 'what',
 'light',
 'through',
 'yonder',
 'window',
 'breaks',
 'It',
 'is',
 'the',
 'east',
 'and',
 'Juliet',
 'is',
 'the',
 'sun',
 'Arise',
 'fair',
 'sun',
 'and',
 'kill',
 'the',
 'envious',
 'moon',
 'Who',
 'is',
 'already',
 'sick',
 'and',
 'pale',
 'with',
 'grief']
```

Comment: Явный перегиб палки, ибо можно просто сразу прочитать все строки файла ```lines = fh.readlines()```, а после получить список: ```lst = ''.join(lines).split()```

Comment: @gregzakharov, как я уже упомянул в ответе - если цель практическая работа с текстом, а не выполнение учебного задания, то модуль NLTK - является лидером в вопросе работы, парсинга и обработки естественных текстов и знакомство с ним может пойти на пользу...

Comment: свободу вероисповедания никто не отменял, однако не вижу смысла для подобного рода тривиальной задачи использование каких-либо сторонних модулей.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен ещё один цикл по каждому слову в строке. Это получится вложенный цикл.

```
for line in fh:
    for word in line.split():
        lst.append(word)
...
```